# TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)-error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python language so when i try to create same file five times i get this error: TypeError: an integer is required (got type str).

Here is my code:

```
def Main():
    troll = 'KURAC'
    for i in range (5):
        with open (i,"login.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(troll + "\n")
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    Main()
```

I tried searching it on web but it didnt do much help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by passing `i` to `open()`?

Comment: Have you tried searching for the docs for the `open` function?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open (i,"login.txt", "w") as f:
```

Error in this line open function take takes filename and mode. you gave 3 arguments.
To create 5 file with name 1login.txt,2login2.txt and so on following code will work.

```
with open (str(i)+"login.txt", "w") as f:
```